# Running a game loop inside a Qt window

Tags: c++, qt

How can I run a game loop inside a Qt window without making a new thread?

My "RunFrame" method looks like this:

```
void GameWindow::RunFrame()
{
    // Update the game time.
    gameTime.Update();
    timeBehind += gameTime.TotalTime() - lastTime;
    lastTime = gameTime.TotalTime();

    while( timeBehind >= targetTimeStep )
    {
        Update();
        timeBehind -= targetTimeStep;
    }

    Draw();
    SwapBuffers();
}
```

As you can see, it runs as if it is getting called every event loop. Is there a way I can get a method in my window to be called every event loop? Or should I redesign my loop around the timers in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think QTimer is a working and relatively simple solution. It uses multimedia timers (if needed) to achive millisecond resolutions so it's feasible for a game loop.